# Render Material UI component down to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with a package that creates a terminal interface in the browser. I can take HTML and we have need to display HTML. Ideally we want to display some Material components in this HTML. The catch is in order for this to work it has to be fed strings. I was able to find a package called `jsx-to-string` which is working to some degree. However, when I try to use a Material UI component and then use this to convert it to a string I see something like this...

```
<withstyles(forwardref(typography))>      Knowledge Check 1     </withstyles(forwardref(typography))>
```

Which looks like it may have issues when attempting to render in the browser in production mode?

I'm wondering if there is a way I can build out some JSX including Material components and even styles and then extract that to a string? Up to this point I've had some troubles trying to get this to work and am not really sure how I can google this

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, but if all you need is to render React code as strings, could you not use ReactDOM.render? And then stringify the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `ReactDOM.render` method to render some React JSX elements as HTML.

From there, you can use `innerHTML` to get the HTML output as a string.

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);

console.log(rootElement.innerHTML) // pass this value to the interface you are building.
```

You can find a simple working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-paper-yh871?file=/src/index.js